# What is the most accessible work of Herman Daly?

Tags: macroeconomics, environmental-economics

I am an undergrad with limited experience in the fields of economics and ecology, and having recently discovered the work of the celebrated economist Herman Daly, who has been writing for decades about sustainable development and the steady-state economy. I'm wondering which of his books is the best **introduction** to his ideas; steady-state economics and others. Considering this may be the only book of  his that I read for a while, I would just like the best overview possible. Thank you.

Comment: Some additional information about your background (e.g. mathematics) may be useful.

Comment: Just to let you form a more complete picture, much of Herman Daly's work is not without controversy. The debate about growth, substitution of capital and the finiteness of the earth's resources between him and other celebrated economists such as Robert Solow and Joseph Stiglitz has been fierce and often ad hominem. Although Daly makes good points I would hesitate to call his work around steady state mainstream economics